# Disabling item in a ComboBox C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, combobox, visual-studio-2005

I have found what seems to be an easy solution to disable certain items in a `ComboBox` in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xftychcy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It states:

> You can disable an item in a list box or combo box  by adding a single
>   backslash to the beginning of the expression.

However if I write

```
testBox.Items.Add("\Test item");
```

or

```
testBox.Items.Add(\"Test item");
```

it gives a syntax error in VS2010. Maybe this function has been disabled in later than 2005 versions?

If I put an item through a VS2010 designer like this

```
\Test item
```

or I write

```
testBox.Items.Add("\\Test item");
```

then it appears with a backslash and not is disabled.

Thus my question is: **is this method somehow available and I just fail to understand how to use it or I do have to create a custom ComboBox to achieve my goal (in title)?**

Comment: The article you mention seems to relate to Visual FoxPro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sadly is it not possible for the combobox control.

I would recommend to just remove the item from the combobox list instead of trying to disable it.

with one of those 3 ways:

```
// To remove item with index 0:
comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
// To remove currently selected item:
comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
// To remove "Tokyo" item:
comboBox1.Items.Remove("Tokyo");
```

If you absolutely need to disable items, you will need to create a custom combobox.

Comment: The documentation he links states it should be possible.

Comment: I suspect it was possible with VS2005, but is no longer supported.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer it was supported in VS2003-2005, but is not longer supported

Comment: @TrizZz Accepted the answer due to your last comment more than the answer itself. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 1:**  This does NOT work, but I'm leaving it as is so the comments below make sense.

**UPDATE 2:**  To answer your question...  After a bit of googling around I believe your only option to achieve this with WinForms is to create your own control as you suggested.

I suspect the rules for working with items that begin with multiple backslashes would apply to escape sequences too.  How about:

```
testBox.Items.Add("\]Test Item");
```

I'm not able to test it out, but it looks like it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error is `Unrecognized escape sequence` :(

Comment: And if you use double-slash-bracket, you just get slash-bracket in the item. I love how that MSDN article has code that won't compile.

Comment: Unfortunately, `("\\]Test Item");` shows up as an enabled `\]Test Item` :(

Comment: I finally got to play around with this.  I can not get any variation of this to work.  I'm suprised the functionality was removed and/or changed.  There's always WPF!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

In general: You need to escape the backslash by writing `\\`. Otherwise the compiler tries to interprete `\T` as an escape sequence (which does not exist). I guess the designer does this for you already, but you can always take a look in the generated source code ;)

About disabling combobox items: The documentation you linked seems to apply for ListBoxes, not ComboBoxes. Furthermore, it refers to VisualFox Pro, not Windows.Forms. So I guess this won't work ;)

According to [this discussion](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?555303-RESOLVED-Disable-some-items-in-a-combobox), you will need to subclass the control and overrride its paint handlers.

But before doing that, I would simply remove (or not even add) those items you wish to disable.

Comment: Then the item looks like `\Test item` and is not disabled.

Comment: Updated the answer, seems like you stumbled over the documentation for the wrong control.

Comment: You can follow a link from the original linked article which takes you to the ComboBox control documentation which includes the same guidance for disabling items.

Comment: Oh true, seems I was too quick in that case.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my mistake. I updated the link in the question :)

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. But I must admit that I have no clue what else could have gone wrong, sorry.

Comment: Yep, its the documentation of a Visual FoxPro control!

Comment: Ouch, reflected this in my answer once again, I will turn the answer into a community wiki.